# NSStatusBar + Swift: title shows and immediately disappear

Tags: swift, macos, nsstatusbar

I want make status bar for macOS, but after I run application title shows and immediately disappears

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        statusItem.title = "Hello"

    }
```

I think something wrong with references, but don't know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed you need a strong reference to the status item

```
var statusItem : NSStatusItem!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        statusItem.title = "Hello"

}
```

However I recommend to use a closure to initialize the status item

```
let statusItem : NSStatusItem = {
    let item =  NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    item.title = "Hello"
    return item
}()
```

Comment: I’ve tried this in Xcode 9 with Swift 4 and it doesn’t work either — the item appears for a blink of an eye and then immediately disappears.