# NSStatusItem dissapears instantly after launching application

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard

I'm working with storyboard and this is the code I have below.

```c
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
  NSStatusItem *status_item = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength: -1];
    [status_item setMenu:_menu_bar_item];
    status_item.button.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"MenuBarIcon"];
    status_item.button.imagePosition = NSImageLeft;
    status_item.button.title = @"foo";
    status_item.button.toolTip = @"bar";
    [status_item setVisible:true];
}
```

The status item does show in the menu bar for like a frame and then instantly dissapears. I've tried it with and without the image and I can't get it to show longer than a split second before it just vanishes. Does anyone know what causes this and how to prevent it?

Comment: Or does this answer your question? [NSStatusBar + Swift: title shows and immediately disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567756/nsstatusbar-swift-title-shows-and-immediately-disappear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the object and then you throw it away.

You need a strong reference for example a property

```
@property (strong) NSStatusItem *status_item;
```

and then

```
status_item = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength: -1];
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew you had to have a strong refrence for the menu but I didn't know you needed one for the status item as well.

Comment: @SeizureSalad `NSStatusItem ` has a strong reference to its menu, you don't to have one.